# how to show one id for multiple data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, multi-database

i have 2 table.
first table for cust. expml :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | Anna |
| 23 | Beth |

and the last one is for stuff

| id_stuff | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Knife |
| 2 | mug |
| 3 | fork |

i want to show data in potgresql like :

| id_stuff | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Anna | Knife |
| 12 | Anna | mug |
| 12 | Anna | fork |
| 23 | Beth | Knife |
| 23 | Beth | mug |
| 23 | Beth | fork |

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is a cross join or Cartesian product:

```
SELECT cust.id, cust.name, stuff.type
FROM cust CROSS JOIN stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select all the tables and you get the same results to CROSS JOIN.

SELECT cust.id, cust.name, stuff.id_stuff, stuff.type
FROM cust, stuff